# Display datetime from database to jsp

Tags: sql, jsp

I inserted time like this in my db:

```
java.util.Date dt = new java.util.Date();
java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf =new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String currentTime = sdf.format(dt);

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/marmota", "root", "root");
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO bids(id, bidder, time, price) VALUES ('" +id + "','" + username + "','" + currentTime + "','" + price + "')");
```

With `getString("something")` you can get a string from db. But how can I get the currentTime I inserted?

Note : I save currentTime as DATETIME into my db.

Comment: read about prepared statement and do not store dates as string you your db

Comment: "NODE i save currentTime as DATETIME in my db." No you do not. You save it as a string

Comment: you can get the `datatime` as string using `date_format()` function, check examples on `date_format()` : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

Answer (score 1):

You don't store the `currentTime` as `DATETIME` type in your DB. According to your code, your save it as `string`:

```
String currentTime = sdf.format(dt);
```

It not a good practise to store time as `string` time in DB, especially when your system's working in different time zones.

So you'd better declare `currentTime` as:

```
java.sql.Time currentTime = new Time(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

And then alter the data type of your `time` field in DB to `datetime` type.
Then your code would work.

Comment: @eXtacy What's the data type of your `time` field in DB?

Comment: i saved currentTime as you suggested . i get exception in insert query.

Answer (score 0):

use [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) for better date & time handling in java